# How to pass or fill Empty value in local storage instead of NULL in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on Angular15. I need help, I have stuck in one problem.

**Scenario:** Based on the requirement I have two text boxes and one submit button. Once I click on the submit button.
I need to store text entered in textbox's into localstorage. But we heed to store "empty" values also.

**Problem:** If I leave the two textboxes as empty. After clicking the submit. It is showing "null" in local storage. But i want to see empty instead of null.

**A.Component.Html:**

```
<ng-container formArrayName="combinations">
  <input id="primaryInput" placeholder="" formControlName="primaryInput" />
  <input id="secondaryInput" placeholder="" formControlName="secondaryInput" />
</ng-container>
<button (click)="search()">Submit</button>
```

**A.component.ts**

```
public advancedForm: FormGroup;

public search(): void {
  localStorage.setItem("advancedForm", JSON.stringify(this.advancedForm.value));
}
```

I tried to do it with `value=""`. Still it is showing `null`.

```
<ng-container formArrayName="combinations">
  <input id="primaryInput" placeholder="" formControlName="primaryInput" value=""/>
  <input id="secondaryInput" placeholder="" formControlName="secondaryInput" Value="" />
</ng-container>
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it an issue that it's null? Also, why are you using `JSON.stringify()`? Are you encoding JSON data? Value should already be a string. It looks like your `advancedForm.value` is null.